# How to resolve upper case lower case in copy file function While copying file over network

Tags: excel, vba

Requirement:
To push (copy) whatever file is in Source Folder to the Path specified in dest string variable (which is basically IP address of pcs on a same network). There are multiple paths on network.

Problem:
Folder at destination locations is named user but it culd be written in upper case or lower case. If destination folder is on lower case
         files copies without problem but if destination folder is in upper case (USER) then file is not copying.

I am trying with the help of If else but it is not working. Is there a way to use MATCASE expression with CopyFile function ?
or any other way to do it ?

Please guide.

```
Sub pushFile()

    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Dim spath As String
    spath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.PATH & "\Source Folder\"
    Filename = Dir(spath & "\*.*")

    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Activate
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim dest As String
    Dim dest2 As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        dest = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
        dest2 = "\\" & dest & "\USER\"
        dest = "\\" & dest & "\user\"

        On Error Resume Next
        If FSO.FolderExists(dest) = True Then
            FSO.CopyFile (spath & Filename), dest, True
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i).Value = dest
         ElseIf FSO.FolderExists(dest2) = True Then
            FSO.CopyFile (spath & Filename), dest2, True
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = dest2
         Else
             MsgBox "Error"
         End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: AFAIK, file paths are not case sensitive. `C:\mypath` is the same as `C:\MYPATH` OR `C:\MyPaTh` Are you sure that is the problem? you may want to use DIR to check if a folder exists before copying the file across

Comment: Note that you must remove `On Error Resume Next` in order to see and fix your errors. This line hides **all** error messages until `End Sub`. If you don't see the errors you cannot fix them and your code does not work. See [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling). Remove that line and fix your errors (ask a proper question telling which errors you get, if you get stuck) • Can you please [edit] and give proper example data what exactly is in the sheet? Also please include which operating systems are involved (source and destination).

Comment: Note that `ActiveWorkbook` is maybe not the workbook you expect. It is the workbook that has focus (is on top) at the moment your code runs (the user can change the active workbook by a single click and your code might not work anymore). Unless you write an add-in it is more likely that you meant to use `ThisWorkbook` which is exactly the workbook this code is written in. Also try to stay away of `ActiveSheet` if possible. Instead use the name of a worksheet `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet name")` for better reliability.

Comment: @SiddharthRout That is not 100% true, if the destination server/computer is on Linux or Mac file paths and filenames can indeed be case sensitive. Since destination `dest = "\\" & dest & "\user\"` is obviously on another machine this might be the issue. I'm not sure if FSO can handle that or consider them as the same, but actually a Linux computer could have `\\linux-server\USER` and a `\\linux-server\user` folder which are not the same (at least for Linux, don't know what FSO in Windows does with them).

Comment: @My apologies. I should have mentioned that I was referring to Win machines. I am computer illiterate when it come to linux :)

Comment: Ok, I removed the On Error Resume Next line. And removed the IF-Else expression too.
Now if destination address contains folder user, files copies fine. But if folder name is in upper case like 
USER then code gives PATH not dound error on line FSO.CopyFile (spath & Filename), dest, True. 
I have checked USER folder exists at destination path. 
Range("B" & i) contains IP Address like 10.10.12.2 what i want to make it to is \\10.10.12.2\user. For i = 2 To lastRow
        dest = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
      dest = "\\" & dest & "\user\"
     FSO.CopyFile (spath & Filename), dest, True

Comment: @D.Ace Can you please answer my question about the operating system on the destination computers?

Comment: Operating system on destination is Windows Server 2008 R2 and on source machine it is windows 7.

Comment: @D.Ace Well, in default mode these operating systems don't make any difference between `\\server\USER` and `\\server\user` (for Windows this is the same folder), so there should be no error because of this. Please [edit] your question and include the exact values of the variables `spath`, `Filename` and `dest` at the time the error occurs. • Test what happens if you type `\\server\USER` and `\\server\user` into the address line of Windows Explorer (use the path that produced the error), does it open the folder in both cases?

Comment: Also check what `Dir("\\server\USER")` and `Dir("\\server\user")` gives you :)

Comment: Also note that if the folder `spath` is empty and has no files then `Filename = Dir(spath & "\*.*")` returns an empty string and then `CopyFile` fails because it cannot copy folders. • In this case you get the error because the source file does not exist (and not because of the destination path). So check `If Filename = vbNullString Then MsgBox "Source path has no files": Exit Sub`.

Comment: @PEH: Issue is with the access of some of the IPs. Administrator has blocked access with \\. These IPs are accessible only with ftp@.* nomenclature. But don't know how to write file once path opens with this method.

Comment: @D.Ace well, check with your Administrator then, we cannot tell. You probably need an FTP client/Iibrary to upload a file to a ftp server. This is too broad to answer, we cannot know the configuration of your systems. But it probably does not work with the FileSystemObject.